# How to get row contact id after insert?

Tags: android

I insert a contact. How to get the row contact Id?

```
//insert a contact
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());
// insert email, phone, structuredpostal and other 
// things of the contact using withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentProviderResult[] res = cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops); 
if (null != res){ id = res[0].uri.getLastPathSegment();}
```